# Issue with child height

Tags: html, css

Okay, so i have my parent DIV (black), and 3 children.

**CSS rules:**

```
#parent{
   height:130px;
}
#description{
   max-height: 80px;
}
```

And that's actually pretty much it for now.

**What I am trying to do**

`#title` should resize according to text inside. It can be from one, to 5-6 lines of text (it's a `span`, can be `div` - any difference?)
`#city` is like 99% of the time one line text (one word actually). Might happen text gets too long, and needs to be wrapped to two lines.
`#description` is a div, which CANNOT go outside the parent box. I need it to have dynamic height - as for later, i use some plugin to cut the text according to height of it and add "..." in the end.

Image shows what it looks like now, when i put too much text in title, and i would like, description to be max 80px, but CAN be less, if `#title` takes more place.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwq2L3y7/2/)

[image]

EDIT: Changed image

Comment: Adding `overflow: hidden` to `#parent` seems to do the trick: https://jsfiddle.net/kwq2L3y7/3/

Comment: But it cuts the `#description` and I need it to change its height, as for my plugin to add "..." works on height. If its even possible

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `flexbox` for such a layout. It may not provide you with a pixel perfect layout on the kind of complex rules you have, but it will still be a powerful way to control.

***Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/kwq2L3y7/6/***

***Snippet***:

```css
#parent {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px; width: 80px;
    float: left; margin: 16px;
    display: flex; flex-direction: column;
}
#title {
    flex: 2 1 auto; /* can grow twice, can shrink, auto height */
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}
#city {
    flex: 1 1 20px; /* can grow, can shrink, accommodate in 20px */
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#description {
    flex: 0 1 80px; /* cannot grow, can shrink, accommodate in 80px */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"> 
    <div id='title'>Title</div>
    <div id="city">City</div>
    <div id="description">Description</div>
</div>
<div id="parent"> 
    <div id='title'>Long Title can be of several lines and can grow many lines</div>
    <div id="city">City can be in 2 lines</div>
    <div id="description">Description which is very long and it will not grow beyond 80px</div>
</div>
<div id="parent"> 
    <div id='title'>Title</div>
    <div id="city">City can be in 2 lines what if it is larger</div>
    <div id="description">Description will remain at 80px</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This flex thing, what browsers does it work on? All modern? Where can i find this informations?

Comment: @Kedor: All modern browsers support `flex`. Check: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 0):

What you want to get, you need to set `height: 100%` in #description.

Use like this:

```
#parent{
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#description{
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kwq2L3y7/4/)

You may display the text in ellipsis.

Comment: Well, sorry, but `overflow: hidden` just hides the rest of the `#description` and i wish `#description` had `overflow: hidden`, but this div itself, can't go outside parent box. (see new image / jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you exactly want to do, but you should have a look on the 'overflow' method with for example:

```
#parent{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

or

```
#parent{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: New image, and new fiddle might give you a hint. Cant use `overflow: hidden` on parent. That doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want the height to be dynamic, you could try use `min-height`

```
#parent {
    min-height:130px;
    width: 80px;
}
#description {
    min-height: 80px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arty_/x8f7v25h/

Comment: sorry, but I actually want the exact opposite. It can be small, even for 1 line or even 1 px, but it CANT resize parent, nor have height that goes over parents borders.